# Understanding chef cookbook snippet

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I am not able to interpret the below code in Chef cookbook:

```
systemd_unit '<service_name>' do      
   action %i[enable start]
end
```

I read about systemd_unit from [systemd_unit resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/systemd_unit/). However, how is action determined here? I am trying to convert this cookbook to ansible and wanted to understand whats happening in cookbook first.

Also, being new to cookbook, I also wanted to confirm if:

```
include_recipe '<cookbook_name>'
```

is provided then my understanding is, it includes `default.rb` from the given cookbook and other recipes within that cookbook are not included. Please let me know, if that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing an expanded answer in addition to the answer by @Psyreactor.

Actions in a Chef recipe are represented by Ruby [symbols](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/02/ruby-symbols/), like `:create`, `:start`, etc. When multiple actions are to be performed on the same resource, they are passed as an array.

So instead of writing two resource declarations for the same service like this:

```rb
# Enable the service
systemd_unit '<service_name>' do 
  action :enable
end

# Start the service
systemd_unit '<service_name>' do 
  action :start
end
```

It can be written as one:

```rb
# Enable and start the service
systemd_unit '<service_name>' do 
  action [ :enable, :start ]
end
```

**Note:** `%i` is a way to omit the use of `:` character and create an array of symbols. `%i(enable, start)` is the same as `[ :enable, :start ]`.

Chef "actions" are known as "state" in Ansible. So for a similar service in Ansible, you would do:

```yaml
systemd:
  name: '<service_name>'
  enabled: yes
  state: 'started'
```

> it includes `default.rb` from the given cookbook and other recipes within that cookbook are not included.

That's correct. However, other recipes from that cookbook *not getting included* in the run depends on that `default.rb`.

Answer (score 2):

%i[start, enable] is an array, the service first starts and then is enabled to start automatically.

The include cookbook only include of default recipe, for a specific recipe use include 'cookbook::recipe'

Best Regards